# The _ScaffoldLayout custom multichild layout delegate forgot to lay out the following child

Tags: charts, drop-down-menu, dart, flutter

Is possible to show dropdown and line chart together, because in my code when I put it together my screen was blank. the error was

> The _ScaffoldLayout custom multichild layout delegate forgot to lay out the following child

```
new Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          new InputDecorator(
              child: new DropdownButton(
                value: this.widget._currentCampaign,
                items: this.widget._dropDownMenuItems,
                onChanged: changedDropDownItem,
              )
          ),
          new Container(
            child: charts.LineChart(_createStatisticData(this.widget.asignList),
                animate: false,
                defaultRenderer: new charts.LineRendererConfig(includePoints: true)),
          )
        ],
      ),
```

any body can help me?

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was when defining the stateful widget. I have typo in the createState() code